# shopware 5: Unable to load template snippet

Tags: php, code-snippets, shopware

I am using shopware 5 for my e-commerce website and I am getting this error when logging to the backend:

```
 [![Unable to load template snippet][1]][1] 'string:{include file=&quot;backend/order/model/order_history.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/order.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/billing.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/shipping.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/tax.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/debit.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/payment.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/payment_instance.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/voucher.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/configuration.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/receipt.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/position.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/mail.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/detail_batch.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/list_batch.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/model/dispatch.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/main/window.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/window.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/overview.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/communication.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/position.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/document.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/detail.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/billing.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/shipping.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/debit.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/order_history.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/configuration.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/detail/dispatch.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/list/filter.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/list/list.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/list/navigation.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/list/position.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/list/document.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/mail/window.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/mail/form.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/mail/attachment.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/batch/window.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/batch/form.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/batch/list.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/view/batch/progress.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/order_history.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/order.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/voucher.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/doc_type.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/configuration.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/batch.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/tax.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/detail_batch.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/list_batch.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/store/document_registry.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/controller/main.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/controller/list.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/controller/filter.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/controller/detail.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/controller/batch.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/controller/mail.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/controller/document.js&quot;} {include file=&quot;backend/order/controller/attachment.js&quot;}|backend/order/payment_methods/controller/detail.js|backend/order/payment_methods/view/detail/payment_methods.js' in engine/Library/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127
```

The problem showed when I migrate the site to another server, and now I can't neither add an order or get list of the orders from the backend
Is there anyone who can help me in this?

Note that the files shown in the error already exist.

Comment: Are you using plugins? Did you write an own plugin?

Comment: no unfortunately I didn't

Comment: I didn't find a solution for this, but for the ones who might have the simular issue, I zipped the project from the old host and unzipped on the new one. I think there was some missed files that didn't uploaded correctly. This trick solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you solved your question your own, just some additional info:

- I recommend ssh-connection, when it comes to moving data, files and such from one server to another. It has several advantages like it is incredible fast, you won't have to handle a file that you down and upload, and also, there are some built-in functions, that make sure, that really all data is sent and received.
- I assume, the zipping, downloading, uploading and unzipping may harmed some core files. So this will most certainly have caused the fault, since the function which is responsible for loading the snippets can't run properly.
- Maybe think about formatting the error message for better readability.

Have a nice day.